# Comparing two rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, comparison

**Scenario**

A very large size query returns a lot of fields from multiple joined tables.
Some records seem to be duplicated.
You accomplish some checks, some grouping. You focus on a couple of records for further investigation.
Still, there are too much fields to check each value.

**Question**

Is there any built-in function that compares two records, returning TRUE if the records match, otherwise FALSE and the set of not matching fields?

Comment: Maybe review the database design.  Are you missing some unique constraints that would prevent the duplicates in the first place.

Comment: Good point, but before altering the db design, I would to understand where duplicate rows come from. Hence my question.

Comment: After you get a handle on your data.  I would create new table(s) with the proper constraints and then select into them using group by rather than delete duplicates and alter.  Delete duplicates is kind of tricky and with a new table if you make a mistake you can start over.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`CHECKSUM`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189788.aspx) function should help identify matching rows

```
 SELECT CHECKSUM(*) FROM table
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable 
GROUP BY <<ColumnList>>
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Just developing on the suggestion provide by Podiluska to find the records which are duplicates

```
SELECT CHECKSUM(*) 
FROM YourTable 
GROUP BY CHECKSUM(*) 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that use the [`hashbytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174415.aspx) function to compare rows.It is better than checksum.

What about creating a row_number and parttion by all the columns and then select all the rows which are having the rn as 2 and above? This is not slow method as well as it will give you perfect data and will give the full row's data which is being duplicated.I would go with this method instead of relying on all the hashing techniques..

Comment: Why Hashbytes is better than Checksum?

Comment: Hashbytes is slower, but less likely to produce false positives. Crucially though in this situation, it lacks the (*) syntax

Comment: What about creating a row_number and parttion by all the columns and then select all the rows which are having the rn as 2 and above. This is not slow method as well as it will give you perfect data and will give the full row's data which is being duplicated.

Comment: @ Gulli Meel: in which cases does `checksum` produce wrong results? Why `hashytes` does not?

Comment: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/microsoft-business-intelligence-and-data-warehousing/2012/02/01/checksum-vs-hashbytes/                                                           You can find similar posts on net.But for you I would suggest that you use the row_number method to find the duplicates ,if I got your intention right that is what you are trying to achieve to find all duplicate records..

Comment: @ADC Gulli is inaccurate. `checksum` reduces a given quantity of data (X) into a 32-bit integer.  Two completely different data sets (X, Y) can possibly produce the same integer since there only 2^32 possible values for that integer.  `hashbytes` [with MD5] reduces data into 2^128 different possible values.  The likelihood of X and Y both reducing to the same MD5 value is very drastically reduced -- but *not* impossible.  The only *absolutely* foolproof method is to compare X and Y directly.